# Operator function '==' requires that 'Entry' conform to 'Equatable'

Tags: swift

I have some code using if which i want to write in one line to make it compact ..entry is enum

```
if Session.shared.input?.entry == .confirm {
                isButtonValidate = true
}
```

I want to make it optimised as

```
isButtonValidate = Session.shared.input?.entry == .confirm // Operator function '==' requires that 'Entry' conform to 'Equatable
```

what is the way to make it correct.
Thank You for help.

Comment: And what is Entry?

Comment: Entry is enum.  i update question

Comment: Show us the definition of that `enum`.

Answer (score 1):

you could try this approach, especially if you do not have access to Entry:

```
 extension Entry: Equatable {
     static func == (lhs: Entry, rhs: Entry) -> Bool {
         lhs.id == rhs.id // <-- here, whatever is appropriate for you
     }
 }
```

Comment: It's an enum, therefore unlikely to contain any kind of `id`. Probably the only thing necessary is to add `Equatable` declaration, or just make it `RawRepresentable`.

Comment: The comment in my answer is clear, "whatever is appropriate for you".
Obviously `id` was just an example of the approach, since the OP does not show
 what `Entry` is.